# Problems binding property on control to controls in a tooltip

Tags: wpf, data-binding, tooltip

My application uses WPF for the presentation layer.  I have a `UserControl` in my code, whose XAML is shown below:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CarSystem.CustomControls.ReadPushPin"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:cs="clr-namespace:CarSystem.CustomControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             DataContext="{Binding Path=Read, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
             d:DesignHeight="30"
             d:DesignWidth="30">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <cs:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibility" True="Visible" False="Collapsed" />
        <cs:DateConverterForRadDateTimePicker x:Key="DateConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Image Name="MarkerImage"
           Source="{Binding Path=Source, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type cs:ReadPushPin}}}">
        <Image.ToolTip>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Column="0"
                       Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       Height="45"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       Source="{Binding Path=ThumbnailImage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type cs:ReadPushPin}}}"
                       Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}, Path=HasThumbnail, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type cs:ReadPushPin}}}"
                       Width="60" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                           Grid.Row="1"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                           Text="Plate:" />
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Plate}" />
                    <TextBlock Text=", " />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=State}" />
                </StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                           Grid.Row="2"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                           Text="Time:" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                           Grid.Row="2"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                           Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}, Path=TimeStamp}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                           Grid.Row="3"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                           Text="Nearest Address:" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                           Grid.Row="3"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                           Text="{Binding Path=NearestAddress, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type cs:ReadPushPin}}}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                           Grid.Row="4"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                           Text="Cross Street:" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                           Grid.Row="4"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                           Text="{Binding Path=CrossStreet, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type cs:ReadPushPin}}}" />
            </Grid>
        </Image.ToolTip>
    </Image>
</UserControl>
```

There are a number of DependencyProperties defined in the code-behind that are bound to the various controls in the Image's ToolTip property.

My problem is that the bindings on the ThumbnailImage, HasThumbnail, NearestAddress, and CrossStreet properties aren't working.  I see errors like the following in the Debug Output window when the program runs:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='CarSystem.CustomControls.ReadPushPin', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=CrossStreet; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

What am I doing wrong?  How do I get the bindings to work?

Tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the problem has to do with the ToolTip not being in the same visual tree as the control it belongs to.

I solved the problem by adding properties to the view model object for each control in the ToolTip template.  As I needed to include a thumbnail image, and I'm storing images in my database as byte arrays, I wrote a class that implements IValueConverter that converts a byte array into a BitmapImage.

This all works.  Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

This error appears whenever your relative binding is evaluated and can't find the parent specified. You ask it to find ReadPushPin control and it's not found in the visual tree.

Looking at the code I suppose your ReadPushPin is the UserControl specified here. Then you should set relative source ancestor type to UserControl. That would do the trick.

Also, I suppose you're setting DataContext on this control and try to get bound values from it using relativeSource. Binding engine finds the first non-null parent datacontext whenever the current element datacontext is null, thus you could simple binding like

And it would look up the visual hierarchy to the UserControl and take it's DataContext.

Comment: I'm not using the RelativeSource binding on anything that can be found in the DataContext.  I moved the NearestAddress and CrossStreet properties to the object in the DataContext & they're coming up. It's the ThumbnailImage & HasThumbnail properties I need to fix now.  I'll try changing the type to UserControl & see what happens.